# Laravel php artisan queue work and stop if jobs are empty

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-artisan

How to execute php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty inside controller i tried to call it inside php artisan like below

```
    $execute = artisan::call('php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty');
```

But nothing happened, can you kindly help

Answer (score 2):

```
\Artisan::call('queue:work --stop-when-empty');
```

It can be called anywhere in the Class. Like if you want to start the queue working and want it would stop whenever the queue's empty then you can use this. I would prefer you to use the queue: work in scheduler instead of calling directly. Like this.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) 
{ 
  $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute(); 
}
```

Comment: Can please you add comment to your code ?

Comment: It can be called anywhere in the Class. Like if you want to start the queue working and want it would stop whenever the queue's empty then you can use this. I would prefer you to use the queue: work in scheduler instead of calling directly. Like this .                             protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {        $schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute();
    }

Comment: thanks, it would be more readable and usefull if you update your answer